# Date Util in java that will explode date range in weeks,month,quarter,year

Tags: java, date

I am looking for a java library that when given from and to date would  return a list of dates in weeks,months,quarter or year which ever is most applicable. I have done this manually and i wanted to know if this is already implemented and tested as a part of a standard package.

Example

Given 1/1/2009 , 1/4/2009 it should give 1/1/2009,1/2/2009,1/3/2009,1/4/2009

Given 1/1/2009 , 1/14/2009 it should give 1/1/2009,1/7/2009,1/14/2009

hope you that is clear :)

Comment: The first example indicates the start date itself should be included, the second contradicts this. Which is correct?

Comment: sorry - you need to include both start and end days - updated the example

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class provided by [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) has methods such as `plusDays(int)`, `plusWeeks(int)`, `plusMonths(int)` which should help.

Assuming you want to get all the dates between `start` and `end` in weeks (pseudocode):

```
DateTime start = // whatever
DateTime end = // whatever

List<DateTime> datesBetween = new ArrayList<DateTime>();

while (start <= end) {
   datesBetween.add(start);
   DateTime dateBetween = start.plusWeeks(1);
   start = dateBetween;
}
```

Comment: '<=' is undefined for datetime. You need to use something like 'start.compareTo(end) <= 0'

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3):

Alternative to Jado is use standart java API

```
Calendar start = // whatever
Calendar end = // whatever

List<Calendar> datesBetween = new ArrayList<Calendar>();

while (start.compareTo(end) <= 0) {
   datesBetween.add(start);
   Calendar dateBetween = start.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
   start = dateBetween;
}
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

## java.time

The [Answer by Dónal using Joda-Time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2020908/642706) is correct, but outdated. The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) team has advised that we should migrate to the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later. Much of the java.time functionality has been [back-ported to Java 6 & 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further [adapted to Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

### `LocalDate`

For a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone, use the `LocalDate` class.

### Half-Open

Generally the best practice in handling a span of time is known as Half-Open. In this approach, the beginning of the span is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So with the example code below, you will see the results do not include the `stop` date. If you insist on the ending being inclusive, change the `date.isBefore ( stop )` to `! date.isAfter ( stop )`.

### Example code

In its current state, the Question is vague, not addressing issues such as whether to consider if the start date happens to align with start of week or start of month and so on. Another issue: whether to use the Half-Open approach or not. So those issues are left as an exercise for the reader. ;-)

This code counts the number of days in the span of time. If under a week, we loop day-by-day. If over a week, we loop week-by-week. The same logic could be extended to handle month-by-month, quarter-by-quarter, and year-by-year as mentioned in the Question.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of ( 2016 , Month.JANUARY , 2 );
LocalDate stop = start.plusDays ( 4 );
// LocalDate stop = start.plusWeeks ( 4 );

long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between ( start , stop );
List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<> ();

if ( days == 0 ) {
    dates.add ( start );// Just one date, as start equals stop.

} else if ( days < 7 ) {  // Under a week, count day-by-day.
    LocalDate date = start;
    do {
        dates.add ( date );
        // Prep for next loop.
        date = date.plusDays ( 1 );
    } while ( date.isBefore ( stop ) ); // Using “isBefore” for Half-Open approach where ending is exclusive. For inclusive, use “! isAfter”.

} else if ( days > 7 ) {  // Over a week, count week-by-week.
    LocalDate date = start;
    do {
        dates.add ( date );
        // Prep for next loop.
        date = date.plusWeeks ( 1 );
    } while ( date.isBefore ( stop ) ); // Using “isBefore” for Half-Open approach where ending is exclusive. For inclusive, use “! isAfter”.

} else {
    // FIXME: ERROR. Should not be possible.
}
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "start: " + start + " | stop: " + stop + " | dates: " + dates );
```

When run with the line for `stop` adding 4 *days*:

> start: 2016-01-02 | stop: 2016-01-06 | dates: [2016-01-02, 2016-01-03, 2016-01-04, 2016-01-05]

When run with the line for `stop` adding 4 *weeks*:

> start: 2016-01-02 | stop: 2016-01-30 | dates: [2016-01-02, 2016-01-09, 2016-01-16, 2016-01-23]

Answer (score 0):

A sample java implementation using jodatime to create a date split over a large range, with minimal memory footprint.

https://github.com/atulsm/Test_Projects/blob/master/src/DateSplitter.java